# How to use where clause to get the output on the basis of the length of Character's in it

Tags: mysql, where-clause, string-length

So the thing is that I have the following question:
Display the column Brand from the table clothing where length(Brand)=10.

So I used the query: select Brand from clothing where length(Brand)=10;
This gives me the out put as an empty set, so I checked my table to see if it was actually supposed to give an empty set and the answer was no.
So if anyone would be able to tell what's going wrong then that would be of great help
The images for the table and the input I tried are given below.
[Table image and the input I gave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7KQc.png)

Comment: 1) We do not work with pictures - the data must be provided as well-formatted text. 2) There is no a row on the screenshot where the brand name length is strictly 10 chars.

Comment: It'd be much easier to assist you if you post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That means A) a CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements with sample data B) the query used and C) the expected results using the sample data - all as text (not screen shots).

Comment: @Akina Ohh ok ok ok sorry and thanks. New here so didn't know

Comment: You can [edit] the question at any time to improve it, or add additional info, and hopefully avoid it being closed.